# Custom HTTP headers are not set from client

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, browser

A have simple ajax prefilter like following:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Request-My", "something);
});
```

I have a strange situation. On the server side sometimes the header is absent in AJAX request. I didn't find out yet for which browser this happens, but it is repeatable for some clients.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?